# unity spawning items using the update method c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the first spawn go well but when it end (when move.tempColor.a<0)
the finishInterilize wont update to false in time and the case will run over at the next frame resulting in accessing a object that doesn't exist in the line objectsToSpawnList[spawnCount - 1]. it happens because the case is in the update method

**the code**

```
case SpawnState.run:

if (finishInterilize)
{
     GameObject spawnClone = objectsToSpawnList[spawnCount - 1];
     SpawnAndMove move = spawnClone.GetComponent<SpawnAndMove>();
     moveObject(spawnClone);

     if (move.tempColor.a<0)
     {
         finishInterilize = false;
         Debug.Log(finishInterilize);
         state = SpawnState.intirilize;
         spawnCount--;
         Destroy(spawnClone);
     }
}
break;
```

Comment: `Color`'s `Alpha` value cannot be negative and is clamped between `0` and `255`. Meaning that your condition `if ( move.tempColor.a < 0 )` should fail in every case.

Comment: @m.rogalski Correction: Color values are between `0` and `1`. It shows `0` to `255` in the Editor but it is `0` and `1` in code. You made that mistake in your answer too.

Comment: @Programmer Color's channel values are represented by 1 byte and Unity uses percentage value in `Color` type and standard ( 1byte ) value in `Color32` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment `Color` values are one byte wide and they are unsigned ( `0` to `255` ) meaning that the whole color is 4 bytes wide. If you want to decide your logic based on the alpha value you should check if it's equal to `0` instead of lower.

```
// if ( move.tempColor.a < 0 ) // a will have values between 0 and 255
if ( move.tempColor.a == 0 )
{
    finishInterilize = false;
    // rest of your code...
}
```

*Extended answer:*

Unity uses two data types to describe color value. First one is [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) which uses values from `0.00f` up to `1.00f` ( percentage of the value ) and the second one [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) which uses values from `0` up to `255` ( as stated above ). I'm assuming in above example that you're using the `Color32` data type. But in every case these values cannot be lower than `0.00` which is what you're currently checking.

Depending on the color data type used you should check if that color is equal to `0.00` and not below.

Using `Color` data type :

```
if ( move.tempColor.a <= 0.001f ) // not the real 0.00 but still goood enought
```

Using `Color32` data type :

```
if ( move.tempColor.a == 0 )
```

Comment: Answer is spot on. +1

Comment: thanks for the good answer i marked it as answer but in the end i didnt use it i moved all the logic to the spawned object itself anyway nice insight on the issue